# Matlab imwrite function changes the pixel values

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I tried to change some pixel values of a Grayscale image and save it using imwrite in matlab.
no problem with saving.
the problem is when I read it back, some pixel values have been changed. not exactly the same values I assigned to pixels before saving it.
I'm trying to hash images so 1unit difference will effect the hash numbers.

Comment: you'll have to provide more information here... What have you done? What changes have you spotted?

Comment: Specifically, it would help to know (a) file format, and (b) possible `float` to `int` conversions in the process. All file formats I work with are `int`; rounding could be your problem.

Comment: I open a RGB file, convert to grayscale, change shome pixel valuse like: Img(x,y)=Img(x,y)+10; the imwrite(Img,'Img.jpg'); there is no float numbers, all are int. but when I read the Img back it is not same as matrix Img.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by mmgp, JPG can be [lossy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression). That means that some of the information in your image will be lost in favor of storage efficiency.

The rationale behind JPG is somewhat like that behind MP3 -- changes in hues etc. that the human eye is not particularly well-adapted to distinguish will be simplified or removed altogether, thus decreasing the amount of information in the image. The information in a JPG represents a similar-looking, but in fact very different image. This is probably what you're experiencing.

In Matlab, have a look at the output of `help imwrite`. You can give a parameter to the `jpg` write called `'Quality'`, which is a number between 0 and 100, 100 meaning (near-)lossless compression.

Although the JPEG standard *does* allow for (near-)lossless compression, it is not often used in practice (at least, in my field). More popular lossless image formats are PNG, JPEG2000 and TIFF. Read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression#Lossless_compression_methods).

All of these are also available in Matlab's `imwrite` function.